# Difference between mySlickgrid.destroy() and mySlickgrid = null

Tags: slickgrid

I am new to slickgrid and was trying to understand destroy() function.

Was going through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129069/invalid-argument-error-with-slickgrid) about destroying the grid after success call.

Could anyone please let me know what is difference between
`mySlickgrid.destroy()` and `mySlickgrid = null`?

Also, read about some memory leak in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/slickgrid/grid.destroy()/slickgrid/USEHsClQFRc/LgESWlAvOKMJ) link.

Does writing `mySlickgrid = null` would prevent memory leak and serve the same purpose as destroy()?

Answer (score 0):

There are some handlers and events that won't get cleaned up when you just set the grid to null, so you should definitely call destroy on it before nulling it out.  It's possible that also setting it to null causes some stuff to get released (if destroy isn't thorough enough), but I don't know in detail.  I always set it to null after destroying as a best practice.